# Apex class date format

Tags: apex, datetime, format

I have a problem with date format, if anyone knows what should I write in marked place => **"???"**

Here is my code

```
public class SomeClass {

    public class DisplayPositionRecords {

       @AuraEnabled public string positionId;
       @AuraEnabled public string positionName;
       @AuraEnabled public string positionStatus;
       @AuraEnabled public Decimal CarsCount;
       @AuraEnabled public Date OrderData;
       @AuraEnabled public string ordCar;

       public DisplayPositionRecords(){
           positionId = '';
           positionName = '';
           positionStatus = '';
           CarsCount = 0;
           **OrderData = ???;**
           ordCar ='';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want to show a blank, today's date, another default? Reviewing the [class reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) for `Date` will show you how to create `Date` instances.

Comment: I want to show a date, for example when the order was created.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to initialize every variable in your constructor, unless you want to be absolutely sure that each is never null. If you want to put in some date just to have a date, put

```
OrderData = Date.today();
```

and it will have a value. Otherwise, wait until you actually need to set a value and remove the line. 
(Also, unless you might have an error with a null string, no need to set every string to '' in your constructor. But we don't know the rest of your code, so maybe that's a good idea in your case.)